# Ignore tab on empty line in visual studio via editorconfig for resource files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with an editor config file for formatting. 
I do have several Resource files for translations which are generated automatically via Visual Studio.

I'd like to exclude those files from any formatting, but this seems not to be possible since editorconfig doesn't support this directly. https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/228

I now have a section in my editor config which just ignores all formatting for *Designer.cs files

```
[*.Designer.cs]
charset = none
end_of_line = none
insert_final_newline = none
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
tab_width = none
indent_style = none
indent_size = none
# New line preferences
csharp_new_line_before_catch = none
csharp_new_line_before_else = none
csharp_new_line_before_finally = none
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = none
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = none
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses = none
# Indentation preferences
csharp_indent_block_contents = none
csharp_indent_braces = none
csharp_indent_case_contents = none
csharp_indent_case_contents_when_block = none
csharp_indent_labels = none
csharp_indent_switch_labels = none
# Space preferences
csharp_space_after_cast = none
csharp_space_after_colon_in_inheritance_clause = none
csharp_space_after_comma = none
csharp_space_after_dot = none
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = none
csharp_space_after_semicolon_in_for_statement = none
csharp_space_around_binary_operators = none
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = none
csharp_space_before_colon_in_inheritance_clause = none
csharp_space_before_comma = none
csharp_space_before_dot = none
csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets = none
csharp_space_before_semicolon_in_for_statement = none
csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets = none
csharp_space_between_method_call_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = none
csharp_space_between_method_call_name_and_opening_parenthesis = none
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses = none
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = none
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_name_and_open_parenthesis = none
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses = none
csharp_space_between_parentheses = none
csharp_space_between_square_brackets = none

# Wrapping preferences
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = none
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = none

end_of_line = none
insert_final_newline = none
```

For the most part, the above configuration works, but there is one case where the Designer.cs files are still formatted. It does replace indentation (tab) on lines which otherwise are empty. 
[image]

Any hints how i can exclude this from being formatted?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem with given .editorocnfig, I could not.

```
/*
 * TEST PRG
 */

namespace Program
{ 

    internal class TestProgram{             

        private int x;
        protected int y;
        internal int z;
        public int a;

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
        Console.WriteLine(a);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can you please try to create a new folder with same .editorconfig file and try with above code? 
That way, we can eliminate scenario where something else (like yapf) is trimming the spaces in empty line with trailing spaces.

Comment: I get the same behaviour. I created a file named TestProgram.cs and used this name to exclude it in the .editorconfig. But if i use format in Visual Studio 2019, it still does remove the intends of the empty lines